# JavaScript / jQuery setting a content to <div> not sticking after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is my code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="Save" CssClass="StylizedButton" resourcekey="btnSave" />

   <div id="lbltot"></div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
              $("#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>").click(function() {
                  var functionReturn = true;
                  var focusElement = null;
                  var tot = $("<%= lblTotal.ClientID %>").val();
                  var txt1 = $("<%= txt1.ClientID %>").val();
                  var txt2 = $("<%= txt2.ClientID %>").val();
                  var txt3 = $("<%= txt3.ClientID %>").val();
                  var txt4 = $("<%= txt4.ClientID %>").val();
                  var cal = parseInt(txt1) + parseInt(txt2) + parseInt(txt3) + parseInt(txt4);
                  if (cal == 100)
                  { return true; }
                  else {
                      $("lbltot").html("Total must be equal to 100%");  
              focusElement = tot; 
              functionReturn = false;

              }
          });
      });
```

On the client side validation, I have to check the value of the `TextBox`, and the total should be equal to 100.  If true, I should allow it to execute. If not, I need to throw an error stating the total should be 100.

What happens is that, after triggering the submit button, it show the text message only until the postback, and then it disappears. This part:

```
else {
                          $("lbltot").html("Total must be equal to 100%");  
                  focusElement = tot; 
                  functionReturn = false;
}
```

Is there any better way to display the error that persist?

Comment: <div id="lbltot" `runat="server"`></div> Try it like that. Even better would be `asp:placeholder`

Answer (score 0):

You should return that `functionReturn` so that the submit action won't happen